# Ava babel-register not transpiling

Tags: javascript, testing, electron, babeljs, ava

I'm trying to include Ava (migrating from mocha) as my test runner for a react / electron app.

I've got this config in my package.json

```
  "ava": {
    "files": [
      "./app/**/*.spec.js"
    ],
    "source": [
      "./app/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "concurrency": 5,
    "failFast": true,
    "require": [
      "babel-register",
      "ignore-styles",
      "./app/test/setup.js"
    ],
    "babel": {
      "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react"
      ]
    }
  },
```

With my setup.js just being a helper to setup jsdom.

I keep getting an error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { jsdom } from 'jsdom';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

So it seems like `babel-register` isn't being required properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably already found the answer, but I though I would share my solution. For me it was to move the `babel` section out next to the `ava` section like so:

```
{
  "ava": { ... ava config ... },
  "babel": { ... babael config ... }
}
```

Full example

```
{
  "ava": {
    "files": [
      "./app/**/*.spec.js"
    ],
    "source": [
      "./app/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "concurrency": 5,
    "failFast": true,
    "require": [
      "babel-register",
      "ignore-styles",
      "./app/test/setup.js"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "babelrc": false,
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

The reason being that this is what babel search for. Either a `package.json` config or a `.babelrc` file.